# Locating the source of an UnhandledException

Tags: c#, wpf

My program seems to have a bug in it which I'm finding hard to track down. The program is multithreaded and quite complex. In a nutshell it communicates with multiple clients using asynchronous sockets and writes to the database.

A System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException is thrown when I hammer the program with client communications and hold down the enter key to spam writes into the database. At some point in time the exception is thrown which I'm catching with the following snippet of code in the constructor of the main window:

```
    VMMainWindow()
    {
         ...
         System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledException += new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDispatcher_UnhandledException);
         ....
    }

    static void CurrentDispatcher_UnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        string str = e.ToString();
    }
```

I don't have much to work with but I was wondering if someone could suggest some tools or or point me in the right direction to help me detect the location of this exception. The exception in detail is pasted below.

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled   Message=Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
       at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at SupernovaServer.App.Main() in D:\Projects\Supernova Server\Server\obj\x86\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
       Message=Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index
       Source=mscorlib
       ParamName=index
       StackTrace:
            at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
            at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
            at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32 index)
            at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.AdjustBefore(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, Object item, Int32 index)
            at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.ProcessCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
            at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
       InnerException:
```

Comment: The ArgumentOutOfRangeException suggests it's going to be a linq expression evaluating somewhere. The only file which looks like it might contain your code is App.g.cs. I'd look in that class and check my lists aren't empty.

Comment: @jhsowter - How does the ArgumentOutOfRangeException suggest it's linq related? I thought it was a generic exception? 

I've had a look at App.g.cs but there aren't any lists in there

Comment: It's the stack trace under that exception which is a classic linq-related exception. Sorry, should have been clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible that you have multiple threads making concurrent accesses to a collection that isn't thread-safe? Say, one thread removing an item while another is reading or adding? That would definitely cause this type of error. In general, the .NET collection classes (except for those in `System.Collections.Concurrent`) are not thread-safe. You can have multiple readers, but any modification of the collection is going to require exclusive access--protected by a lock or a reader/writer lock.

Comment: Hi Jim, I think this was the problem. I switched to a safe thread collection and I haven't seen it crash after some stress testing. However I have a question - before I had exclusive lock(..){} statements around the collection before I was doing any adds/removes and I had noticed that the program would hang in what seemed like a dead lock. Is this possible when I am using one OBJECT as in my locks? i.e. lock(OBJECT) around all the collection manipulations

Comment: Exclusive `lock` statements around accesses can't create a deadlock situation unless you have locks for multiple collections. You can get into a situation where Thread 1 has lock A and wants to acquire lock B, and Thread 2 has lock B and wants to acquire lock A. That is a distressingly common cause of deadlocks. But I don't know of a way you can deadlock on a single lock.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty safe to assume App.g.cs is not where the problem lies, so as you said, there isn't much to go on.  So here's my hint to you: look at the inner exception.  Those things are quite handy, and I'll be willing to bet you have an inner exception at least one layer deep.

Comment: There is something in the inner exception however it doesn't seem to be my code as it's inside a "System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal" collection

[System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException] {"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"} 
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Data {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}


Source "mscorlib"